# Laravel return Has many relationship

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-6

The relationship is User who can have many Events they are associated to.

I want to be able to make an API call to get all the events associated by the user. I have changed my primary key from id to uuid. I have made the foreign key association to the Events table as well. The primary key in the events table is also a column called UUID.

I am getting error

```
Return value of App\Http\Controllers\UsersController::getAllEvents() must be an instance of App\Http\Resources\UserResource, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany returned
```

My routes table:

```
Route::apiResource('/users', 'UsersController');
Route::apiResource('/events', 'EventsController');
Route::get('/users/allevents/{user}', 'UsersController@getAllEvents');
```

So the URL im hitting is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/allevents/0a0jqZ7qzuhemKnzB3wOPUc2Ugp2
```

**0a0jqZ7qzuhemKnzB3wOPUc2Ugp2** is the UUID of a user. I want to get all the events associated to that user.

My User model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'uuid', 'email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'level', 'venmo'
    ];

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'uuid';
    }

    public function events() {
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }


}
```

My Event Model:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'events';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
//    public function getRouteKeyName()
//    {
//        return 'uuid';
//    }

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'availableSpots', 'uuid', 'chosenDate', 'date', 'epochTime', 'level', 'price', 'time', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'user_uuid'
    ];
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    protected $keyType = 'string';


    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_uuid', 'uuid');
    }
}
```

My UsersController:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function show(User $user): UserResource
    {

        return new UserResource($user);
    }



    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param User $user
     * @return UserResource
     */
    public function update(Request $request, User $user): UserResource
    {
        $user->update($request->all());


        return new UserResource($user);

    }


    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return UserResource
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function destroy(User $user): UserResource
    {
        $user->delete();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }

    public function getAllEvents(User $user): UserResource {
        return $user->events();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong type of the method return it doesn't return UserResource it return events array so by removing the wrong type it will work

```
   public function getAllEvents(User $user) {
        return $user->events;
    }
```

Comment: Oh man that was a blunder. Now I get an error Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string

Comment: Also when does one use a collection? Wouldnt something like this be using an EventsResourceCollection?

Comment: sorry I edited my answer it had a mistake didn't see it

Comment: you don't need a resource it's an optional it's just way of telling laravel how to represent the collection data , collections are given freely when ever you return an eloquent model relationships , query etc

Answer (score 1):

```php
public function getAllEvents(User $user)
{
    return $user->events;
}
```